# Computational Assumption For the extended discrete logarithm

Tags: elliptic-curves, provable-security, identity-based-encryption, certificateless-crypto

Choose randomly $P\in G_1, (s,a \in Z_q)$.

let the attackers know $a,P$ and keep $s$ as secret.
Also the following is given.
 $$sP,(a+s)^{-1}P$$

Individually,

From $sP$, trying to reveal ($s$) will be discrete logarithm problem.

However, I don't know (computational assumption) how to prove  $s$ value cannot be revealed from $(a+s)^{-1}P$.

Moreover, are there any computation assumption to prove the secrecy of  $s$ value from both $sP,(a+s)^{-1}P$ instead of individually.

As there is no pairing operation, BDH, xBDH, wBDH cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a (multiplicatively written) group of order $q$ and let $g$ be a generator of $\mathbb{G}$. The $r$-SDH assumption (Strong Diffie-Hellman) [BB08] states that given
$$
g,g^x, g^{x^2}, \dots, g^{x^r}
$$
as input, it is hard to compute a pair $(a, g^{1/(x+a)})$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_q$.

Writing group $\mathbb{G}$ additively and letting $P$ be a generator of $\mathbb{G}$, the $r$-SDH assumption is: Given
$$ 
P, sP, s^2P, \dots, s^rP
$$
as input, it is hard to compute a pair $(a, 1/(s+a)P)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_q$.

Your assumption is related to the $1$-SDH assumption in a cyclic subgroup of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field.  It is however weaker as the attacker is given the value of $a$ (in the SDH assumption, the attacker is free to choose the value of $a$).

---

[BB08] D. Boneh and X. Boyen, *Short Signatures Without Random Oracles and the SDH Assumption in Bilinear Groups*, Journal of Cryptology, 21(2), pp. 149-177, 2008.

Comment: How about using $G$ as additive group of order $q$? Can I use same assumption?

Comment: @myat: I added a description with additive notation.

Comment: it is hard to compute a pair $(a, g^{1/(x+a)})$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_q$. In my case, as $a $ is known, can I use it?

Comment: In your recommended paper, $1/(x+a)$ value is computed using modulo p. But, here, no modulo value is used. Will this affect the security ?

Comment: @myat: In my answer, since $\mathbb{G}$ has order $q$, the value of $1/(x+a)$ is defined modulo $q$.  The $r$-SDH problem is to find a pair $(a, [(s+a)^{-1} \bmod q]P)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I ask modulo case because I don't use modulo value in my $(s+a)^{-1}$. I just use  $(a,(s+a)^{-1}P)$.

Comment: @myat: We usually don't explicitly  add mod $q$ as it is understood from the group order.  We prefer to simply write $(a, (s+a)^{-1}P)$.

Comment: In my case, as pair $(a,(s+a)^{-1}P$ is given, just want to show the secrecy of $s$. May be somewhat different from $r-$SDH problem. I think so. I will carefully read your recommended paper. Thanks.

Comment: If there is no modulus, then you are not working in a finite group. But that is the basic assumption of the DLOG problem. So yes, not using a modulus does affect security. Most likely there is none in your case. If you consdier $(s+a)^{-1}$ as regular division, you're likely working with rational or real numbers.... there is no DLOG problem for that. And that means no security.